# Java: How to escape all regex metacharacters in a given String?

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a utility method in Java that will escape all regex metacharacters in a given String.

I want to convert this:

```
foo.bar(baz)
```

Into this:

```
foo\.bar\(baz\)
```

So that I can take any sample string and convert it into a regex-friendly search pattern. Surely one must exist, but I cannot seem to find anything.

(`Pattern.quote(String s)` offers something similar to what I need, but not the exact same functionality.)

Comment: `Pattern.quote` does do what you want ("take any sample string and convert it into a regex-friendly search pattern") though it escapes the entire string as a whole rather than individually quoting individual meta-characters in the string.  `foo.bar(baz)` then becomes `\Qfoo.bar(baz)\E`

Comment: It doesn't satisfy my particular use case. For example, as the next step, I want to do:

`text = text.replace(" ","\\s+");`

Comment: @BennettLynch You should put that into the question. But the answer may be that there's nothing that does what you want.

Comment: It might be sufficient to escape every metacharacter, with something like `s.replaceAll("[\\\\[\\]{}().?+*^$]", "\\\\$0")`.

Answer (score 1):

[`Pattern.quote(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) does *exactly* what you want.

Calling `Pattern.quote("foo.bar(baz)")` returns `"\Qfoo.bar(baz)\E"`, which matches exactly the same as the pattern `"foo\.bar\(baz\)"`.

Comment: Pattern.quote won’t satisfy the requirement mentioned in [Bennett’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085277/java-how-to-escape-all-regex-metacharacters-in-a-given-string#comment79133042_46085277).